# Count() how many times a name shows up in a table with the rest of info

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, window-functions

I have read in various websites about the `count()` function but I still cannot make this work.

I made a small table with (id, name, last name, age) and I need to retrieve all columns plus a new one. In this new column I want to display how many times a name shows up or repeats itself in the table.

I have made test and can retrieve but only COLUMN NAME with the count column, but I haven't been able to retrieve all data from the table.

Currently I have this

```
   select a.n_showsup, p.*
   from [test1].[dbo].[person] p,
   (select count(*) n_showsup
    from [test1].[dbo].[person])a
```

This gives me all data on output but on the column n_showsup it gives me just the number of rows, now I know this is because I'm missing a GROUP BY but then when I write group by NAME it shows me a lot of records. This is an example of what I need:

[image: test table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use window functions, if you RDBMS supports them:

```
select t.*, count(*) over(partition by name) n_showsup
from mytable t
```

Alternatively, you can join the table with an aggregation query that counts the number of occurences of each name:

```
select t.*, x.n_showsup
from mytable t
inner join (select name, count(*) n_showsup from mytable group by name) x
    on x.name = t.name
```

Comment: @ed2020 . . . The window function is the best answer to the question and should be accepted.

Comment: @ed2020 As the receiver of the "Accepted Answer" I agree with Gordon here. I wanted to supply my answer as a stepping stone since you were headed in the right direction with your attempt. Ultimately though, the Windows Function approach is going to be much lighter on system resources since it involves an intermediate result set and a join which is just superfluous CPU and RAM usage compared to the Window Function route.

Answer (score 1):

While the window function approach (@GMB's answer) is the right way to go, thinking through this from a subquery approach (like you were headed towards) would look something like:

```
select p.*, a.n_showsup
from [test1].[dbo].[person] p
INNER JOIN (
    select name, count(*) n_showsup
    from [test1].[dbo].[person]
    GROUP BY name
) a ON p.name = a.name
```

This is VERY close to what you had, the difference is that we are grouping that subquery by `name` (so we get a count by name) and we can use that in the join criteria which we do with the `ON` clause on that `INNER JOIN`.

You should really never ever use a comma in your `FROM` clause. Instead use a `JOIN`.

Comment: @ed2020 The term of art is [correlated subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15#correlated).